# Setting a background layer below UITableView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i was following this tutorial for gradients:

http://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/gradient-background-for-uiview-in-ios/

But i cant seem to insert the sub layer below my tableView, the layer is inserted as such:

```
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer blueGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

Why is it going above my storyboard tableView ?

EDIT:

My table view is there, below the layer, i can click it and everything, but i cannot see it

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? Are you adding the table view after inserting the gradient layer?

Comment: called in viewDidLoad

Comment: tableView is added via the storyboard

Comment: try [self.view.layer addSublayer:bgLayer]  and do it before you add tableView to self.view.

Comment: If you're using a subclass of UITableViewController then self.view will still be pointing to the table view, which means the gradient layer will be getting added as sublayer of the table view. If this is the case you may have to use a subclass of UIViewController and add the table view yourself.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way of doing this in a way that the gradient will stay behind the table view and not scroll when the tableView scrolls is to set the gradient in the backgroundView of the tableView

How to do this in Swift 3

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
let bgView = UIView.init(frame: self.tableView.frame)
bgView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
self.tableView.backgroundView = bgView
```

Comment: What if also using a UIRefreshControl? This best works when setting it as backgroundView too. So both seems to be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you put it in viewDidAppear. However, setting the size to self.view.bounds will only make the gradient go to the bottom of the screen -- when you scroll, your gradient will scroll with it. If you want the gradient to be as long as the table view, you have to set its height to the contentSize's height. You also need to set the background color of the cells to clear to see the gradient (in tableView:willDisplayCell:forIndexPath:)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CAGradientLayer *bgGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    bgGradient.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.bounds.origin.x, self.tableView.bounds.origin.y, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
    bgGradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:150/255.0 green:2150/255.0 blue:233/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:208/255.0 green:210/255.0 blue:216/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    bgGradient.locations = @[@0.02f,@1.00f];
    [bgGradient setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgGradient atIndex:0];

}
```

One problem with this approach is that the length, and thus the look, of the gradient will vary depending on the number of rows in you table view. If you want the gradient to stay the same length, you might want to add it to the window instead (and make the table view's background color clear).

Comment: It would only scroll with the table view if self.view is the table view (which would be true when using UITableViewController).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue:

If you are using a `UITableViewController` you need set your custom views in a later stage of the life cycles, such as `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
The reason is in `viewDidLoad` tableView frame is not being set yet.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: tableView.bounds)
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(bgLayer, at: 0)
    
    tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```